# How to remove string until the end of line from a file in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to remove the comments from codes saved in Text files and I have tried everything but haven't been able to do anything about it. I tried this RegEx - `//[^\\n]{0,}` which should've worked theoretically but It didn't.

This is the content of the text file:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a=0;
    cout << a; //Hello World
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what I want the output file to contain:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a=0;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I want the output to be free of any comments in the file.

Comment: Not sure why you said your pattern is not working. It worked on both Java and Python 3.8 for me, both when the contents are read line by line or when the file content is considered as one string.

Comment: What about `url = 'http://blah.com/; // this is the default url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
strng = ''' using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a=0;
    cout << a; //Hello World
    return 0;
}'''

pattern = r'(//.+)'
s = re.sub(pattern,'',strng)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a=0;
    cout << a; 
    return 0;
}
```